# Unable to read file in S3 bucket from SQL Server using Polybase

Tags: sql-server, amazon-s3, polybase

I need to be able to query csv/txt files in an S3 bucket from SQL Server.
I have enabled Polybase and successfully created a master key and scoped credential using an AWS access key and secret for the corresponding bucket.

I have created an external data source:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE s3_ds
WITH
(   LOCATION = 's3://<bucket>:1443'
,   CREDENTIAL = s3_dc
);
GO
```

But when I try and query it I get the error

```
File cannot be opened because it does not exist or it is used by another process.
```

Comment: Are you sure port 1443 is correct?

Comment: There are many authentication options related to S3 storage, have you reviewed them? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-configure-s3-compatible